# Testing APIs with Gherkin/Java and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gherkin, apache-fluent-api

I have been asked to create some automation tests to test an API for a project. I am fairly new to automation testing with limited knowledge of java. The instructions I have been given include; create a BDD style test suite using cucumber/gherkin syntax, utilizing Apache fluent-hc to interrogate the API. I have also been asked to create the test suite using Java. How can I utilize 'Apache fluent-hc' to test my API and can this be done via a Java IDE like 'IntelliJ IDEA'? Thanks

Comment: The question is a bit too broad. Please show examples of what you already tried and where you are stuck. If you haven't even digged into the topic, read: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fluent.html and https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed a very general question. I can just say in really short "yes you can use IntelliJ IDEA" for all Java related development.

From the other point, it is something that you have to learn and understand your own, before starting any development, as a sample, in which way your BDD tests will be developed based on the API technology and as you said that you have limited knowledge of Java I would suggest you read first how to create API in Java, of course, it all based on your requirements, but I prefer API development using [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

And if you are interested in that, I will post my blog post URL here later on where I'm describing from 0 to end how to cover APIs with BDD (currently it is under preparation, next week I will post it).

Meanwhile, I will suggest you read [this](http://blazemeter.com/blog) blog and earn some knowledge of APIs and their testing.

**UPDATE:** Here is the blog post about BDD that I promised - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-cucumber-bdd-configuration-tips